# Interpretation of VECM results when the variables are swapped as response variable

Tags: time-series, interpretation, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I have two variables, which is Tomato farmgate price and retail price. When I use VECM, both variables are endogenous. However, there can still be a response variable (ex. when you put the variable first in eviews VAR, it will be counted as the response). My concern is why is ECT significant in both cases where I use the farmgate price and retail price as response variable? Isn't cointegration non-directional? How will I interpret this?

First pic shows the farmgate response variable and a significant and negative ect which is -0.14. Next pic is when response variable is retail and another significant and negative ect which is -0.47. Passed all diagnostic test (normality, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity). So how will I interpret this? Can I conclude this as the correction period when the error is coming from the farmgate or the retail?

Also, can I interpret the long run results in both variables? (For example i got 1% retail and 5.71% farmgate when farmgate prices is the response variables and 1% farmgate is 0.18% retail when i use the retail prices as the response variable.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps print out the estimation results of your model so that we have a more complete and detailed picture?

Comment: @RichardHardy edited it out. Hope you can help me figure this out. Thank you